# Is query context evaluated before filter context in elasticsearch? How to determine the order of evaluation?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I am using the below query :

```
GET customer/doc/_search?routing=123
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "location": "Delhi"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "phone": {
              "query": "650",
              "max_expansions": 100
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is my search on phone isn't working anymore. It used to work fine when I had less data, now every shard has data for multiple locations. Search on phone now requires me to type in 6 or 7 characters at times. (There may be matching phone numbers that have different location but are on this shard)

This is due to max_expansions I am guessing. When I increase it to 500 it does return me search results (not all), but the query becomes slow.

Isn't there a way to force es to apply filter first (and restrict the dataset) and then apply the should clause, so that I get the matching results even with small value of max_expansions?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to max_expansions. Restricting dataset is not exactly what you may want to do ( Thats also not very straight forward - you may have to use some script which will in turn slowdown query).

When you query for a wildcard expression, Lucene expands the wildcard expression into set of actual terms in your inverted index term dictionary. Now , when you restrict the term expansion to 500 - it might miss a few.

I would consider using [prefixes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-prefixes.html) during indexing phase. Prefixes helps to avoid the costly expansion in runtime phase.

Comment: how would using index prefixes help in my case? I am indexing phone numbers with custom analyzer which converts formatted numbers to sequence of digits. I need to be able to search on single digit as well.

Comment: although, n-gram tokenizer might help my case here (although for a cost of storing prefixes) - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

Comment: ngram seems to be better suited for your purpose since its just not prefix search.